# MySQL multi query in one

Tags: mysql

I have a table name `user` with `user_id`, `image_id` .... (and some others attribute)

Another table name `image` with `image_id` and `image_name` ...

I wanna search an `image_id` by `image_name`, and update to user table that `image_id` found

like this:

```
UPDATE person SET image_id = (
     SELECT image_id
     FROM image
     WHERE image.src='02.jpg' ) WHERE person_id=2
```

Of course, it doesn't work. I just use that query to show you what i want. 
I can use 2 queries on php code, the first get `image_id`, the second update it to table.
But I think there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Do you have any error message ?

Comment: The question to ask is - how many `image` rows do you have with `image.src='02.jpg'`

Comment: just one record for image.src='02.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

I think its not right way to use the sub-query in main query, you can create trigger in MySQL database or if you would like to use by this way then:

```
UPDATE person 
SET person.image_id = ( SELECT image_id 
                        FROM image 
                        WHERE image_name='02.jpg' 
                       ) 
WHERE person.person_id=2
```

Comment: ya, it doesnt work
i just write it to show you what i mean :)

Comment: image_id should be primary in image table and image_id should be exist in image table for image_name='02.jpg'

Comment: yes
SELECT image_id FROM image WHERE image_name='02.jpg' 
that query always get 1 record :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here might well be that the subselect is returning more than one row and you are trying to update only one row in the table person.
Try that:

```
UPDATE person SET image_id = ( SELECT distinct image_id FROM image WHERE image.src='02.jpg' ) WHERE person_id=2
```

Can we see the error?

Comment: The **image.src** should just be the name of the column **src** I guess

Answer (score 0):

update person p set p.image_id=(select i.image_id from images i where i.src='02.jpg' limit 1 ) where p.person_id=2

step 1: use table alias ( p, i ) so your fieldnames are not ambiguously

step 2: use limit 1 on subselect -> get not more than 1 rows

Better solution is to use some logic on serverside (php/perl...) and work with two seperate querys

Hope it helps...
Thomas

Comment: im sure, it always get only 1 record with the query selete :)